# Datastax Opscenter 5.1.1 cant connect to cluster after client-to-node encryption

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I am trying to setup internode and client encryption on cassandra. I set
up a small ca, generated the certificates, distributed them and configured
the nodes to use them.

Internode encryption worked straight forward, cqlsh after I added "--ssl".

But I am not able to setup OpsCenter (running 5.1.1). Two issues:

1. I added the ca file path, for me /etc/opscenter/cassandra_ca.pem, as
   asked. I cant save the cluster until I add a keystore even if I did not set
   a mark for client verification - also I cant find any documentation which
   keystore is meant here. Since OpsCenter is python these are obviously not
   the jks keystores from cassandra.

I guess that it is meant in that way, the individual nodes present thier
certificate to opscenter which would verify it against the ca-store.

2. Trying to connect gives me an error in opscenterd.log:

> ```
> 2015-05-26 10:20:49+0000 []  INFO: Using SSL when checking thrift connection: /etc/cassandra/cassandra_ca.crt, client_pem=None, client_key=None, validate=True
> 2015-05-26 10:20:49+0000 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x7fa4868c03b0>
> 2015-05-26 10:20:49+0000 [] Unhandled Error
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
>             return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
>             return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/context.py", line 59, in callWithContext
>             return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/context.py", line 37, in callWithContext
>             return func(*args,**kw)
>         --- <exception caught here> ---
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 220, in _doReadOrWrite
>             why = selectable.doWrite()
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 664, in doConnect
>             self._connectDone()
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/ssl.py", line 160, in _connectDone
>             self.startTLS(self.ctxFactory)
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 561, in startTLS
>             if Connection.startTLS(self, ctx, client):
>           File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 402, in startTLS
>             self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx.getContext(), self.socket)
>           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/SslUtils.py", line 54, in getContext
>
>           File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 303, in load_verify_locations
>             raise TypeError("cafile must be None or a byte string")
>         exceptions.TypeError: cafile must be None or a byte string
>
> 2015-05-26 10:20:49+0000 []  INFO: <twisted.internet.ssl.Connector instance at 0x7fa4868c05f0> will retry in 2 seconds
> 2015-05-26 10:20:49+0000 []  INFO: Unhandled error in Deferred:
> 2015-05-26 10:20:49+0000 [] Unhandled Error
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>         Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectError: An error occurred while connecting: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: cafile must be None or a byte string
>         ].            ].
> ```

Any hints about this?

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opscenter needs a few things set up work with client-to-node encryption

1. The Opscenter daemon needs a certificate to access the cluster (just like any other client). This should be produced by the same process as documented on the DSE side. JKS keys are required if that's what Cassandra is using for encryption.
2. The Opscenterd certificate needs to be registered in the truststore specified in cassandra.yaml.
3. The agents need to know the path to a keystore that Cassandra is configured to accept. The easiest way is to point them to the keystore specified in cassandra.yaml.

When adding the cluster to opscenter, it will ask for the location of the certificate (for opscenterd) and the location of the keystore (for each cassandra node).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I build a complete PKI already - cassandra_ca as CA Root and all others are signed from that one and it is also in my truststore and in my keystores are the per node certificates signed with my ca. This works fine for alle internode communication.

But for the opscenter - I thought I need the CA certificate as PEM encoded one and put the path of it in opscenter als CA Certificate File Path. 

But I got an error from python twisted - complaining that it expects "None" or "byte string" as cafile. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: I can only claim to have tested it with a private certificate using the same JKS key type as I had configured C* to use.

Comment: How did you produce your PEM certificate?

Comment: I created those with XCA - or with openssl. As far as I can see this is some kind of bug, and I am into stepping through the code.